# Lazy names or bug?

Tags: discussion

Browsing the site, I have noticed that many new users recently started to use default names such as "user398948". At first I just ignored that thinking it may be just a batch of lazy users.

That is, until I readeth about the running bug with rep counter and user names on the main site. Basically, there is a running bug that afflicts some user on SO that afflicts the calculated rep and display name: anyone affected will end up as "user#" with a reseted rep score.

It shouldn't be our situation - most of the "user#" users are new... but I believe it may be a good idea to keep an eye open - as far as I know it may depend from a variation of the above bug.

Please, if anyone had noticed something strange, leave a notice here so that we can signal any useful info to the staff. This bug is still escaping fixes, so any clue we may get may be useful.

To be more clear: 
a search for users with a name containing "user" returns 47 pages of results.
the same search, limited to new user (which seems to be user created in the last 60 days?) return 7 pages of results. Seems the proportions are a little of. Keep an eye open.

Comment: The bug that was causing this should be clear by now, so I think that being on alert for will probably no longer be necessary.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks, @GraceNote